# Nunit 3 msbuild task fails in TeamCity 9.1.5

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I'm trying to upgrade to Nunit 3.0.1 and I'm using TeamCity for the ci build.
We used to have this msbuild task to run the nunit tests with versions 2.x but now it fails with the following error with NUnit 3.

```
<Target Name="Test">
    <NUnit Assemblies="@(TestAssembly)" NUnitVersion="NUnit-3.0.1"/>
</Target>
```

[NUnit] Failed to find plugin 'Test/NUnit-3.0.1'
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.Utils.PluginManager.LoadExtensions(String prefix, String plugin) in c:\BuildAgent\work\ad31cec0a1b0f083\src\Utils\src\PluginManager.cs:line 50
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitCommon.NUnitFactory.NUnitRunnerFactory.ContainsNUnitPlugin(ITestRunArguments myArguments) in c:\BuildAgent\work\ad31cec0a1b0f083\src\NUnitCommon\src\NUnitFactory\NUnitRunnerFactory.cs:line 34
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitCommon.NUnitFactory.NUnitRunnerFactory.CreateRunner(ITestRunArguments myArguments) in c:\BuildAgent\work\ad31cec0a1b0f083\src\NUnitCommon\src\NUnitFactory\NUnitRunnerFactory.cs:line 43
   at JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers.RunnerFactory.FindTestRunner(ITestRunArguments arguments) in c:\BuildAgent\work\ad31cec0a1b0f083\src\NUnitBootstrap\src\RunnerFactory.cs:line 46
   at JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers.RunnerFactory.CreateTestRunner(ITestRunArguments arguments) in c:\BuildAgent\work\ad31cec0a1b0f083\src\NUnitBootstrap\src\RunnerFactory.cs:line 31
   at JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers.NUnitLauncher2.Run2(String[] args) in c:\BuildAgent\work\ad31cec0a1b0f083\src\NUnitBootstrap\src\NUnitLauncher2.cs:line 100
   at JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers.NUnitLauncher2.Run(String[] args) in c:\BuildAgent\work\ad31cec0a1b0f083\src\NUnitBootstrap\src\NUnitLauncher2.cs:line 56
[11:14:09][NUnit] D:\BuildAgent\work\3e91aa62371f2902\teamcity\tc_unittest.xml(22, 3): D:\BuildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe "@@" D:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\tmp24F.tmp exited with code -42.

I tried also with version 3.0.0, 3.0 and 3 but the same error is returned.
From TeamCity documentation Nunit 3.0 should be supported. See:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/NUnit+for+MSBuild

Any idea of what I can be missing?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-43784

Answer (score 0):

As stated by JetBrains support, the builtin msbuild nunit task is not and won't be supported from 3.0 and forward.

The only alternative is to install the nunit console on the agent (exactly what I wanted to avoid) and then run the test through either the teamcity nunit runner or a msbuild exec task.

For reference:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-43784
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Getting+Started+with+NUnit#GettingStartedwithNUnit-Case2.MSBuild